# What's the exact meaning of Persistence model in NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

I'm new in the work with the Orm's and This question occurred for me that what the **Persistence Model** in NHibernate and what the difference between **transient** object and **persistent** object.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the definitions from [nhibernate](/questions/tagged/nhibernate)'s [documentation](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#architecture-overview):

> **Persistent Objects and Collections**
>
> Short-lived, single threaded objects containing persistent state and
>   business function. These might be ordinary POCOs, the only special
>   thing about them is that they are currently associated with (exactly
>   one) ISession. As soon as the Session is closed, they will be detached
>   and free to use in any application layer (e.g. directly as data
>   transfer objects to and from presentation).
>
> **Transient Objects and Collections**
>
> Instances of persistent classes that are not currently associated with
>   a ISession. They may have been instantiated by the application and not
>   (yet) persisted or they may have been instantiated by a closed
>   ISession.

And on [instance states](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#architecture-states):

> An instance of a persistent classes may be in one of three different
>   states, which are defined with respect to a persistence context. The
>   NHibernate ISession object is the persistence context:
>
> **transient**
>
> The instance is not, and has never been associated with any
>   persistence context. It has no persistent identity (primary key
>   value).
>
> **persistent**
>
> The instance is currently associated with a persistence context. It
>   has a persistent identity (primary key value) and, perhaps, a
>   corresponding row in the database. For a particular persistence
>   context, NHibernate guarantees that persistent identity is equivalent
>   to CLR identity (in-memory location of the object).
>
> **detached**
>
> The instance was once associated with a persistence context, but that
>   context was closed, or the instance was serialized to another process.
>   It has a persistent identity and, perhaps, a corrsponding row in the
>   database. For detached instances, NHibernate makes no guarantees about
>   the relationship between persistent identity and CLR identity.